# Simple SPARQL Query

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am working from this example, and I want to archieve the same, however with a different topic - Climate change

All i need to output is the abstract from this page: http://dbpedia.org/page/Climate_change

```
PREFIX dbp-res:     <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbp-ont:    <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbp-prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
   SELECT *
   WHERE
   {
?Resource a dbp-ont:Agent .
?Resource dbp-ont:abstract ?Description .
?Resource rdfs:label ?Label .
 FILTER( STR(?Label) = 'Climate_change' )
 FILTER (langMatches(lang(?Description),'en'))
 FILTER (langMatches(lang(?Label),'en'))

}
```

The problem seems to be the Agent, but I have no clue, as to what to replace it with.

[My query](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=PREFIX%20dbp-res%3A%20%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbp-ont%3A%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbp-prop%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20*%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%3FResource%20a%20dbp-ont%3AAgent%20.%0D%0A%3FResource%20dbp-ont%3Aabstract%20%3FDescription%20.%0D%0A%3FResource%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FLabel%20.%0D%0A%20FILTER%28%20STR%28%3FLabel%29%20%3D%20%27Greenpeace%27%20%29%0D%0A%20FILTER%20%28langMatches%28lang%28%3FDescription%29%2C%27en%27%29%29%0D%0A%20FILTER%20%28langMatches%28lang%28%3FLabel%29%2C%27en%27%29%29%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve for if you are interested only in the abstract of http://dbpedia.org/page/Climate_change, you can easily get it with  `SELECT *
WHERE
{
dbp-res:Climate_change dbo:abstract ?Abstract .
 FILTER (langMatches(lang(?Abstract),'en'))`

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. The query that links to DBpedia is different and works, yes. But copy-and-paste is not always helpful. Not everything is of type `Agent`, I hope you understand what this means in general. If you look at your example resource, it only belongs to `Organisation`. And as Ivo pointed out, most things in your query are redundant, starting from the resource URI itself is the way to go.

Comment: One of your immediate problems is that the [Resource](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Climate_change) for which you want the Abstract does not have a Label of `'Climate_change'` but rather of `'Climate change'` (space, not underscore). As @AKSW notes, it's also not `a dbp-ont:Agent`; it is `a dbp-ont:Organisation` — but since you already know the specific Resource, you don't need to know nor specify its `rdf:type` for this query.